# Handling CompletableFuture exceptions in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I'm trying to get into `CompletableFuture` class for a project I'm running, and I got to some question here:

There is the following method: it tries to find a conversation by its ID or hash; and, if not found, it throws an exception. So far, so good.

```
public ConversationOutput getConversationByIdOrHash(String conversationIdOrHash)
            throws ConversationNotFoundException {
        Conversation conversation = this.conversationRepository.getByIdOrHash(conversationIdOrHash);

        if (conversation == null) {
            throw new ConversationNotFoundException(conversationIdOrHash);
        }

        return this.modelMapper.map(conversation, ConversationOutput.class);
    }
```

Note that I am throwing `ConversationNotFoundException` from my method signature. My SpringBoot controller is reacting to this exception and it's all working fine since the beginning.

What I'm trying to do is to make this to a `CompletableFuture` return and actually throwing an exception, something similar to:

```
    public CompletableFuture<ConversationOutput> getConversationByIdOrHashAsync(String conversationIdOrHash)
            throws ConversationNotFoundException {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.getConversationByIdOrHash(conversationIdOrHash));
}
```

I've seen posts where people use `exceptionally` to handle exceptions, but what I really want to do is to throw it to my controller and let it handle it. Any suggestions of how can I make it?

Thank you all!

Comment: A CompletableFuture (or any Future) makes sense when you delegate the execution to a different Thread (run something async). Are you doing something like that?

Comment: Yes, @Juan. I want to delegate the execution of a database query to another thread and see how it goes. The real goal is to create CompletableFutures from complex and timing executions that we have in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is do you care about the result of `CompletableFuture`.
`CompletableFuture` is like a special task and it is processed on other thread. If you don't invoke `.join()` you won't receive the results of `CompletableFuture`. This method also will propagate the exception if any occured. However it waits for `CompletableFuture` to finish and blocks the request.
However, there is no way to get exceptions from the inside of the `CompletableFuture` without waiting, you have to treat it like other task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Kapcer. Yes, I do care about the result. I'm trying to mimic some async/await behaviour that exist in Javascript/.NET. Let me try to work with it a bit and see how can i get into something with `.join()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the completed future in case of a success, and failed future along with your custom exception.

```java
public CompletableFuture<ConversationOutput> getConversationByIdOrHashAsync(String conversationIdOrHash) {
        try {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.getConversationByIdOrHash(conversationIdOrHash));
        } catch (ConversationNotFoundException e) {
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e);
        }
    }
```

and then at your controller level you can handle the exception.

```java
final CompletableFuture<ConversationOutput> future = getConversationByIdOrHashAsync("idOrHash");
        future.whenComplete((r, e) -> {
            if (e != null) {
                if (e instanceof ConversationNotFoundException) {
                    //handling
                }
            }
        });
```